# Projection before join table is more efficient for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query which returns me the result after more than one minute:

```
select distinct o.OMS_IDTOPO,e.TYPEQPTL,e.LIBUPR,
                o.OMS_SITEA,o.OMS_SITEB,
            siteA.Code_Postal as CPA, siteB.Code_Postal as CPB,
            siteA.Nom_court as NomA, siteB.Nom_court as NomB,
            siteA.Commune as ComA,siteB.Commune as ComB,
            siteA.Lat_GPS as latA,siteA.Long_GPS as longA,
            siteB.Lat_GPS as latB,siteB.Long_GPS as longB 
from occ_wdm_oms as o 
left join noeud_dico_traitement  as siteA on o.OMS_IDNOEUDA=siteA.Code_DICO
left join noeud_dico_traitement  as siteB on o.OMS_IDNOEUDB=siteB.Code_DICO
left join  occ_wdm_eqpt as e on o.OMS_IDTOPO=e.OMS_IDTOPO
where o.OMS_IDTOPO NOT LIKE '%.VP%'
and  siteA.Lat_GPS != 0 and siteA.Long_GPS != 0 
and  siteB.Lat_GPS != 0 and siteB.Long_GPS != 0;
```

However, if I make a projection like

```
select distinct o.OMS_IDTOPO,e.TYPEQPTL,e.LIBUPR,
                o.OMS_SITEA,o.OMS_SITEB,
            siteA.Code_Postal as CPA, siteB.Code_Postal as CPB,
            siteA.Nom_court as NomA, siteB.Nom_court as NomB,
            siteA.Commune as ComA,siteB.Commune as ComB,
            siteA.Lat_GPS as latA,siteA.Long_GPS as longA,
            siteB.Lat_GPS as latB,siteB.Long_GPS as longB 
from occ_wdm_oms as o 
left join noeud_dico_traitement  as siteA on o.OMS_IDNOEUDA=siteA.Code_DICO
left join noeud_dico_traitement  as siteB on o.OMS_IDNOEUDB=siteB.Code_DICO

left join (select distinct LIBUPR,TYPEQPTL,OMS_IDTOPO from occ_wdm_eqpt) as e on o.OMS_IDTOPO=e.OMS_IDTOPO

where o.OMS_IDTOPO NOT LIKE '%.VP%'
and  siteA.Lat_GPS != 0 and siteA.Long_GPS != 0 
and  siteB.Lat_GPS != 0 and siteB.Long_GPS != 0;
```

It takes just 10 seconds.

I've found two similar questions :[Which MySQL JOIN query is more efficient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725856/which-mysql-join-query-is-more-efficient) and [Optimizing join in vertica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32224728/optimizing-join-in-vertica).

The answers tell me that normally the first version is more efficient.

And I explain the two query, the result looks like tell me the same thing.

[Explain for first query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDt8x.png)

[Explain for another query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w46vb.png)

I'm confused because in reality I get the result more quickly by the query with projection, if there are something I've missed ?

Comment: Site A and Site B are INNER JOINs. Just sayin'!

Comment: Thanks for reply, it just make no difference

Comment: There's no derived table in the first query. I think you've got something muddled up.

Comment: The problem appears to be a lack of  usable indexes on the first and fourth tables. Fix that, and your problems will miraculously disappear.

Comment: Do those queries return the same output? You have a distinct in the top of your query, so you are not able to see if both returns the same. Try to remove it and see if the first query returns much more records than the second one. The fields from occ_wdm_eqpt could be repeated several times in the first query, joining with all of them. However, in the second query you would be joining just with the distinct values

Comment: yes, same result, but I'll try your advise, thanks @JaimeDrq

Comment: I would add a composite index on some permutation of OMS_IDNOEUDA,OMS_IDNOEUDB,OMS_IDTOPO

Comment: @Strawberry I'll try your advise